# Better way to assign events? MouseListener

Tags: scala

Is there a "better" way to do this?

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent
trait MouseListener  extends java.awt.event.MouseListener{
    def mouseClicked(e:MouseEvent){}
    def mousePressed(e:MouseEvent){}
    def mouseReleased(e:MouseEvent){}
    def mouseEntered(e:MouseEvent){}
    def mouseExited(e:MouseEvent){}
}
```

I made this trait so I could do this without overriding the methods I am not using.
This works fine I am just wondering if there is an alternative method?

```
new ActionListener{
    override def mouseClicked(e:MouseEvent){
        //Blah Blah
    }
}
```

Comment: The title should give a hint what your question is about, like "Better way to assign events" or so

Comment: You should specify what you want. With some effort you could even implement C#-like syntax: `someObject.mouseClicked += {e => ...}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "better" way, I suppose you mean "Scala way."

[On a scala.swing.UIElement](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.10.2/#scala.swing.UIElement):

```
  listenTo(mouse.clicks, mouse.moves, mouse.wheel, keys)

  reactions += {
    case e: MousePressed => startDrag(e)
    case e: MouseDragged => doDrag(e)
    case e: MouseReleased => endDrag(e)
    case e: MouseWheelMoved => wheeling(e)
    case _ => null // println ("Unreacted event")
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is built-in already: [MouseAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html). There are similar classes for other Swing listener interfaces with more than one method.